# PHPUnit and CodeIgniter - Fatal error: Class 'CIUnit_TestCase' not found

Tags: php, codeigniter

I currently have a set up where on my local pc I have a CodeIgniter website, with CIUnit and phpunit installed for Unit Testing. Everything works fine here.  I can go into the tests dir and type phpunit and all the unit tests run like normal. yay

Today I set up a buildserver and installed Hudson and phpunit and created a build file and everything for it to run.  The build fails because the unit tests break everything. I try to go to the tests dir /var/lib/hudson/jobs/website/workspace/tests and type phpunit and I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'CIUnit_TestCase' not found in /var/lib/hudson/jobs/website/workspace/tests/controllers/CI_Unit_Test_class_Test.php on line 8
```

I know there isn't an issue with the code being different because it is pulled in during the build from a git repo.  I can't for the life of me figure out why it works locally but not on the build server.

Both machines are running Ubuntu 12.04

Can anyone please give me some advice or insight on what to check?  I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Is your local setup a windows machine? I can't tell from this information, but it could be uppercase/lowercase filename mismatches.

Comment: @complex857 - Both machines are running Ubuntu 12.04.  Ill edit the main post to show this.

Answer (score 0):

I have to run the command phpunit under Tests folder, not in its subfolders. for example:

instead of

tests/model/  phpnuit sometest.php
use

tests/ phpunit model/sometest.php

Hope this helps please check.